# Difference between this property descriptor and property assignment in ECMAScript 5?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I am reading up a little more on ECMAScript 5 (in the browser, using the [ES5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) which I know doesn't support everything). And just to clear up any confusion, considering I have this object (stolen from [this post](http://uxebu.com/blog/2011/02/23/object-based-inheritance-for-ecmascript-5/)):

```
var Person = {
    firstName: null, // the person’s first name
    lastName: null // the person’s last name
};
```

Is there any difference between this:

```
var Employee = Object.create(Person, {
    id: {
        value: null,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true,
        writable: true
    }
});
```

And this:

```
var Employee = Object.create(Person);
Employee.id = null;

// Or using jQuery.extend
$.extend(Employee, {
    id : null
});
```

As far as I understood enumerable, configurable and writable are set to true when defining a property this way (which would also be backwards compatible to legacy JavaScript engines). Am I missing something or can I just omit the verbose property descriptors whenever I want this to be the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're the same.

When creating new properties by assignment

```
obj.prop = val;
```

all three Boolean attributes of the newly created property are set to `true`.

---

Also, notice that when adding properties via `Object.defineProperty`

```
Object.defineProperty( obj, 'prop', {
    value: val
});
```

the Boolean attributes are set to `false` (by default).

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to make sure. I also noticed that the default values when using a property descriptor are different. I am still a little careful using it since the shim defaults back in legacy systems anyway.